# Write comma-delimited text file in vba, elegantly

Tags: excel, vba

I just have to ask this for once...

Is there a more elegant way of having your output comma-delimited, than the tried and tested `& "," &` we always use?

```
print #myTextFileNumber, myValue1 & "," & myText2 & "," & myValue3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store your values in an array, you can use `join`.

Answer (score 3):

the command you are looking for is `write`

from the help:

> the Write # statement inserts commas between items and quotation marks around strings as they are written to the file

in your example, then command would be:

```
write #myTextFileNumber, myValue1 , myText2 , myValue3
```

Comment: Thanks, the thing is: Sometimes I don't want the quotation marks, only the commas.

Comment: then you are going to have to use `join` as @chrisneilsen gives, or keep with the way you are doing it now